# Iron Python How to justify left right or center in Table or CrossTable

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

Thanks in advance.

I am using Iron Python to load data into visualization.   sometimes, it is Table, sometimes, it is CrossTable.

The requirement is all the data and labels should be left justified in some visualizations and centered in some others.

How to justify using Iron Python?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! What have you tried? Please provide a code snippet that is failing, or a specific problem which you are trying to overcome. For instance, have you tried `string.ljust(s, width[, fillchar])`?

Comment: I don't know what is the syntax for alignment in Iron python.  I need a sample code.  I am using the following in 2 different visualizations:

MainViz.TypeId = VisualTypeIdentifiers.Table
chart = MainViz.As[TablePlot]()

MainViz.TypeId = VisualTypeIdentifiers.CrossTable
chart = MainViz.As[CrossTablePlot]()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not possible using IronPython.

You can still achieve what you want using CSS code inside a TextArea but note that this can stop working in future version of spotfire as support is not guaranted (it edits internal Spotfire comportment). It will also affect the whole page on which you put the display, and not only one table.

Insert a TextArea (inside the visualization toolbar). Then right click and click on edit HTML. Add the code below and save.

To align left :

```
<STYLE>
.flex-justify-center {
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
}
.flex-justify-end {
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
}
<STYLE>
```

To align center :

```
<STYLE>
.flex-justify-start {
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-center;
    justify-content: flex-center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
}
.flex-justify-end {
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-center;
    justify-content: flex-center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
}
<STYLE>
```

Comment: Hi Txemsukr,   Thanks a lot for the response.    I dont want to do in text area.  I have lot of process based on this visualization.   Thanks for this code.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome! You can't do what you want using IronPython, and to do it using CSS you need to use a TextArea. You can reduce it to the minimum so that it doesn't take too much space, or, even better, use an existing textarea of your page. Feel free to upvote and accept this answer if you think that it is answering well your question ;)

Comment: Though this is not serving my purpose, this is the good answer.  Thanks.